# Run Function Every "X" hours for "X" Seconds over 24 hours

Tags: python, datetime, timer, setinterval, argparse

I need to make a system where the user can set a timer that goes off every x hours for x minutes (ideally starting from 0600 or at least on the 00 seconds of the actual time) over 24 hours

below is an example of the code i am trying to do, the problem is when it hits 00:00 (midnight) it goes back to being not ready.

```
import time
import argparse
from datetime import datetime 

def main(start_time_hour, start_time_minute, watering_duration, 
watering_interval_hour, watering_interval_minute):

# Watering loop, each cycle consists one application of water per watering 
cycle.
while True:

    # Sleep until start time is reached. Resets every 24 hours.
    current_time = datetime.now()
    while current_time.hour < start_time_hour:              # This loop will only break after start hour is reached,
        time.sleep(1)                                       # at which point it will only pass for remainder of 24h
        current_time = datetime.now()
        print('Not Ready - Hour')
        while current_time.minute < start_time_minute:     # This loop will only break after start minute is reached,
            time.sleep(1)                                   # at which point the watering routine will execute for
            current_time = datetime.now()                   # the remainder of the 24 hour period
            print('Not Ready - minute')
    while current_time.hour <= start_time_hour and current_time.minute < start_time_minute:              # This loop will only break after start hour is reached,
        time.sleep(1)                                       # at which point it will only pass for remainder of 24h
        current_time = datetime.now()
        print('Not Ready - minute')

    # Commence watering loop
    print("call function to turn sprinkler valve relay ON here")
    print('On time:', datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    time.sleep(watering_duration)
    print("call function to turn sprinkler valve relay OFF here")
    print('Off time:', datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    time.sleep(watering_interval_hour * 3600 + watering_interval_minute * 60 - watering_duration)


if __name__ == '__main__':
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Watering timer code. Takes user input args and prints events to stdout")
parser.add_argument('start_time', metavar='start_time %s', help='start time in HHMM format with leading zeroes')
parser.add_argument('watering_duration', metavar='watering_duration %s', help='watering duration in seconds')
parser.add_argument('watering_interval', metavar='watering_interval %s', help='watering interval in HHMM format with leading zeroes')
args = parser.parse_args()

main(int(args.start_time[0:2]), int(args.start_time[2:4]), int(args.watering_duration),
     int(args.watering_interval[0:2]), int(args.watering_interval[2:4]))
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: try out schedule, its a neat python library suitable for your needs. 
 https://pypi.org/project/schedule/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux **crontab** is a good option for the automated scheduler Job.
The crontab is a list of commands that you want to run on a regular schedule, 
and also the user-defined functions/program it will be executed within the regular interval of time.

Usage:

MIN HOUR DOM MON DOW CMD

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/action-trigger.sh
```

**MIN** :   Minute field    0 to 59

**HOUR** :  Hour field  0 to 23

**DOM** : Day of Month  1-31

**MON** :   Month field 1-12

**DOW** : Day Of Week   0-6

**CMD** :   Command Any command to be executed

Comment: thanks for the information, i was able to solve my problem using your advice, sorry it took me so long to mark your response and upvote, i was new to the site (still am lol) i was wondering if you could give me some advice on why my question got a down vote, i want to make sure i do the right thing on this site and im not sure why my question got a down vote lol. thanks again for your help.